# ASP.NET, MVC 3, EF 4.1: Filtering data based on ASP.NET Authentication login

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0, specifications

If you have a decent layered ASP.NET MVC 3 web application with a data service class pumping out view models pulled from a repository, sending JSON to an Ajax client,

[taking a breath]

what's a good way to add data filtering based on ASP.NET logins and roles without really messing up our data service class with these concerns?

We have a repository that kicks out Entity Framework 4.1 POCOs which accepts Lambda Expressions for where clauses (or specification objects.)

The data service class creates query objects (like IQueryable) then returns them with .ToList() in the return statement.

I'm thinking maybe a specification that handles security roles passed to the data service class, or somehow essentially injecting a Lambda Expression in just the right place in the data service class?

I am sure there is a fairly standardized pattern to implement something like this.  Links to examples or books on the subject would be most appreciated.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038640/where-should-i-put-code-for-access-permisions-in-my-asp-net-mvc-site/6038694#6038694

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that allows or disallows the method to run.  I need to run the method, but filter the data coming from the method prior to .ToList() (prior to leaving the method but without mucking up the method with security concerns.)

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a single-tiered application (as in, your web layer and service/data layer all run in the same process) then it's common to use a custom principal to achieve what you want.

You can use a custom principal to store extra data about a user (have a watch of this: http://www.asp.net/security/videos/use-custom-principal-objects), but the trick is to set this custom principal into the current thread's principal also, by doing `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = myPrincipal`

This effectively means that you can get access to your user/role information from deep into your service layer without creating extra parameters on your methods (which is bad design). You can do this by querying `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and cast it to your own implementation.

If your service/data layer exists in a different process (perhaps you're using web services) then you can still pass your user information separately from your method calls, by passing custom data headers along with the service request and leave this kind of data out of your method calls.

Edit: to relate back to your querying of data, obviously any queries you write which are influence by some aspect of the currently logged-in user or their role can be picked up by looking at the data in your custom principal, but without passing special data through your method calls.

Hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if you are using DI, as you mentioned you have your layers split up properly I am presuming so, then again this should be possible without DI I think...

Create an interface called IUserSession or something similar, Implement that inside your asp.net mvc application, the interface can contain something like GetUser(); from this info I am sure you can filter data inside your middle tier, otherwise you can simply use this IUserSession inside your web application and do the filtering inside that tier...

See: https://gist.github.com/1042173